"Login failed for user 'AD\MyUser'." ... 0x80004005 "Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed."
The full error message:

MyPackageName:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
an OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Login failed for user 'AD\MyUser'.". An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed.".

And one follow-up error message:

MyDataFlowTaskName:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The AcquireConnectionm method call to the connection manager "MyConnectionManager" failed with error code 0xC0202009. There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

I need to run a SELECT TSQL query on a database. How can I get around the login error?

Perhaps it helps showing how the whole setting is done in SSMS to get it to work.
Find out which user you need to add to your database users. Since I run a deployed SSIS package in this example, the report of the SSISDB catalog shows the "Caller" at the top right (red underlined):

And the error, which also has the caller in it:

MyPackageName:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
an OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Login failed for user 'AD\MyUser=the caller'.". An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed.".

The caller on the top right shows the name. Add a new user with this name, if it is not already there:

Put dbo (or whatever schema) as the "Default schema":

Mark db_owner as schema owned by this user:

Give rights for schemas of your choice that are in the database:

Or you can choose the tables as objects as well:


And give the schema SELECT rights or more:

Run the job or the chosen job step from the SQL Agent and check whether the login works.
